# Link Column in Django Tables 2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm currently trying to add a `Link column` into a table that I have created already using Django tables 2.

I'm using the following code from the documentation

```
class PeopleTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.LinkColumn('people_detail', text='static text', args=[A('pk')])
```

view.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('people/(\d+)/', views.people_detail, name='people_detail')
)
```

The problem is, when i try to load my webpage i get the following error:
`Reverse for 'people_detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Can anyone see the problem here?

EDIT: My url.py looks like the following:

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.IndexView, name='index'),

url(r'^Search/$', views.SearchView, name='Search'),

url(r'^people/(\d+)/$', views.myview,{}, name='people_detail'),

url(r'^comment/$', views.LicenseComment, name='comment'),

url(r'^copyLicense/$', views.copyLicense, name='Copy'),

url(r'^download/$', views.download, name='Download'),

url(r'^AddMod/$', views.addModule, name='addMod'),

url(r'^removeMod/$', views.removeModule, name='removeMod'),

url(r'^login/$', views.Login.as_view(), name='login'),

url(r'^logout/$', views.LogOut, name='logout'),

url(r'^create/$', views.get_name, name='create'),

url(r'^NewLicense/$', views.NewLicense.as_view(), name='NewLicense'),

url(r'^LicenseCharts/$', views.Chart.as_view(), name='ViewChart'),

url(r'^Advancedsearch/$', views.Adsearch.as_view(), name='AdSearch'),

url(r'^AdvancedRequest/$', views.AdvancedRequest, name='AdvancedRequest'),

url(r'^EditLicense/$', views.EditLicense.as_view(), name='EditLic'),

url(r'^Profile/$', views.profileView.as_view(), name='profile'),

url(r'^GlobalLog/$', views.LogFile.as_view(), name='LogFile'),

]
```

Also if i remove the `text='static files'` from where i create the link column, this error no longer appears, but the table just contains a column called Name that contains only a dash

Comment: Can you show the exact contents of your `urls.py`?

Comment: Did you include that `urls.py` with a namespace? If so you might need to do something like: `name = tables.LinkColumn('myapp:people_detail', text='static text', args=[A('pk')])`

Comment: No that's actually it, can't believe i actually forgot to include that. Alasdair can you put that as a answer please, so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you included your urls.py with a namespace, then you have to include the namespace when defining the link column. For example:

```
class PeopleTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.LinkColumn('myapp:people_detail', text='static text', args=[A('pk')])
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar scenario

My app name - "ecart"

**url.py** (under ecart app) 
path("ecart/edit/...", edit_ecart, name="edit_ecart") 
**tables.py** (exists under same hierarchy i.e. ecart app)

from django_tables2.utils import A 
import django_tables2 as tables

class CartTable(tables.Table):
     edit_col = tables.LinkColumn('edit_ecart', text='EDIT', args=[A('pk')] ) 
     ----------
     ----------

This will show EDIT hyperlink column as last column in table

**Note**: I did not required to add namespace name, i.e "ecart:edit_ecart" as both the above files are in same hierarchy